# socket.io connection event not working, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am new to nodejs and express and trying the socket.io just a simple chat application. Its very simple code everything is just fine but there is no event fired logs on the node console. Connection event code is not working.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(http),
    start = require('./routes/index.js');

app.use('/', start);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
});

module.exports = app;
```

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
head
    script(type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.3.js")
    script.
        var socket = io();

body
    block content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listening on **http** instead of **app**. Like this:

```
var server = http.listen(3000, function () {
...
```

Comment: Worked ! Tnx! Perfect